# get a function of external file

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I am using jQuery and my js file thats calling a jquery function resides in totally different directory than jQuery is in. I need to call this function reloadPage like this from js file

```
reloadPage({param1:'First Parameter', param2:ID});
```

but it gives me an error

```
Line: 341
Error: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

Line 341 is `reloadPage({param1:'First Parameter', param2:ID});`. What can I do to run this function from outside the directory?

I tried

```
parent.reloadPage({param1:'First Parameter', param2:ID});
```

But that didnt work either.

Comment: Need to see the HTML where you include the files in question, please. Also, remember that they get included in the order they appear in your web page, so you'll have to include the file where the function is defined before you include the file where that function is called (unless you call it on document.ready or something).

Comment: This question makes little sense. What difference does it make what "directory" you script files are in?

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you are including your javascripts in your document, add another script tag with the relevant file path and that will allow you to call a function that lives in that file.

```
<script src="path/to/your/file" type="text/javascript></script>
```